# Is it required to make two identical S3 buckets to host your domain (example.com) and (www.example.com) through Cloudfront and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

When I first deployed my app through S3, Cloudfront, and Route 53, navigating to www.mydomain.com did not work, but mydomain.com worked.

I couldn't make another alias in Route 53 without creating another origin domain in Cloudfront, and I couldn't make another origin domain without another S3 bucket.

So now I have 2 identical S3 buckets, and I'm not sure if it is necessary, not to mention the extra work deploying every iteration.

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 identical buckets with your content in both?

Comment: Yes. However I just deleted the duplicate which was labeled www.mydomain.com and I'm trying to get it so that when you type mydomain.com into a browser, it directs you to https://www.[mydomain].com. Currently, I have it working so it directs you to https://[mydomain].com without the www.

Comment: the above comment created a link.. I want it to direct you to https:// + www. + mydomain + .com